# Why is my facebook lacking formatting or any interactions?

Tags: facebook, css

My Facebook looks pretty weird right now, there is absolutely no formatting whatsoever, like the CSS has been wiped off the page

#### Here are the problems

- There is no background color, text color or font formatting
- I can log in, but cannot view messages, my timeline or newsfeed
- Only two of the 4 accounts on my iMac are affected

Comment: Did you intend to add the `URL` to your FB? Btw: the body text doesn't have an actual question.

Answer (score 2):

This usually happens when it takes too much time for your internet to gather information from the server, or the server is slow, resulting in the cached display. Here are the possible solutions:

- Try using refresh. If that does not work, use the hard refresh, that is `shift` + `refresh` or alternatively `shift`  + `f5`
- There is a huge possibility that you have a slow internet connection. Facebook reportedly needs 1 MB per minute, so check if there are any heavy downloads going on or your internet is too slow to handle it.
- If everything is OK and you are still receiving problems, try switching browsers. That may help.